# Understanding the impact of using resize2fs

Tags: resize2fs

I want to use `resize2fs` to resize partition on my system, will doing so delete any files that is present on the partition or will it use the free space available on the partition to resize the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501392/do-parted-resizepart-and-resize2fs-not-modify-or-remove-existing-files-on-a

Comment: You must backup regardless if you care about your data.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes , Thank you but it also tells we have to shrink the filesystem before using resize2fs on the partition , is there any guide to the same?

Comment: The above is the same as Kusalananda’s first link, but as a close vote.